# How to separate logic from data access while maintaining application level concurrency in database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, separation-of-concerns

I am trying to reserve orders for an item. But to do that, I need to be able to fetch the items and lock them so that other concurrent reads and writes are blocked till I update or release the lock. The way release will be guaranteed to be called will be through the use of try-finally block.

How can I block read and writes to a table or some rows while maintaining separation of concerns of logic and data access?

The use case is along the lines of:

```py
def use_case(input, repository):
    validate_input(input)
    try:
        data = repository.get_data()

        if condition1 and condition2:
            update_data()
    finally:
        repository.unlock()
```

The way I implemented repository is:

```py
class Repository:
    def get_data():
         conn = adapter.connect()
         cur = conn.cursor()

         cur.execute('select * from table where condition')

         cur.close()
         conn.close()

    def update():
         conn = adapter.connect()
         cur = conn.cursor()

         cur.execute('update table set field = value where condition')

         cur.close()
         conn.close()
    
    def unlock():
         pass
```

I have tried select for update, explicit locking and Advisory locks but they all release when the connection is closed and rightly so.

I could have used optimistic locking but the problem is I am updating multiple columns at once. And even if the value of once column changes, I need to rerun my logic.

The reason I am creating separate connections is to avoid idle connections by only creating them when I need them. I don't know if this is the standard way of doing things.

Comment: Your use case is not clear. if you want to lock rows for longer than a database connection, how do you make sure rows don't get left in place forever? How do you determine who can call `updata_data` and who is locked? Please describe your goal in detail. That doesn't look like "classic select for update problem" to me.

Comment: I tried to communicate my intent better @LaurenzAlbe. Check the question now

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is there way I can do this without writing a monolith that fetches the data, validates input and updates the data?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a monolith. That is, I know what a monolith is, but I don't see how it can refer to your 10 lines of code.

Comment: Maybe I basically mean to ask what lock can I use that is connection agnostic @LaurenzAlbe. The answer is probably a optimistic lock

Comment: It cannot be a database lock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220607/discussion-between-hemil-and-laurenz-albe).

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two options: optimistic and pessimistic locking:

- With **pessimistic locking**, all happens inside a single database transaction. You `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, and you release the lock by committing the transaction.

  Pessimistic locking is good if the whole **action is short** (no user interactions!), particularly if the likelihood of conflicts is high.
- **Optimistic locking** is not bound to database transactions (although you can implement it using `REPEATABLE READ` transactions). You remember the original values of all columns and use `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` condition that checks that all the values are still the same (nobody modified the row). If a concurrent transaction modified the row (no row was updated), you repeat the whole action.

  Optimistic locking is good if the action takes long or if the likelihood of a conflict is low.

Comment: I know about locking. The problem is to lock, you need to be in the same transaction. I don't know about the best practices but if you look properly, I am creating a different connection for select and update. I did that to facilitate easy testing because there is not state. If I create the connection object in the constructor, I might have a idle connection for too long. The only real option seems to be optimistic locking. The only problem there is because I need to reserve all or nothing, I need to rerun my business logic in case of conflict

Comment: My question is more about how to separate business logic from database while locking in different connections than how and which lock to use in this case